# switch cuda compute mode to default mode

Tags: cuda, gpu

I use `nvidia-smi` to see the status of each GPU on a computing node but find one of them is `E. Thread`. Is there any easy way to switch it back to `default mode?` 

`------------------------------------------------------+

| NVIDIA-SMI 346.46     Driver Version: 346.46         |

|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce GTX 680     Off  | 0000:03:00.0     N/A |                  N/A |
| 30%   30C    P8    N/A /  N/A |     10MiB /  4095MiB |     N/A    E. Thread |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   1  GeForce GTX 680     Off  | 0000:04:00.0     N/A |                  N/A |
| 30%   29C    P8    N/A /  N/A |     10MiB /  4095MiB |     N/A      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
nvidia-smi -h
```

will give you command line help, and there is also a man page:

```
man nvidia-smi
```

the following command should reset that device to compute mode of 0 (default)

```
nvidia-smi -i 0 -c 0
```

should reset that device (0) to compute mode of 0 (default)

You need to have root privilege to modify the device this way, so either be a root user or run the command with `sudo`

Comment: I am looking at the nvidia-smi manual. Nowhere does it mention which numbers in compute mode (0, 1, 2, 3) refer to which mode!

Comment: @user13107  `nvidia-smi -h` (the very first thing I said in my answer).  I did that for the 387.26 driver and it says: `-c,   --compute-mode=       Set MODE for compute applications:
                                0/DEFAULT, 1/EXCLUSIVE_PROCESS,
                                2/PROHIBITED`  3 is not not listed and 1 has been changed to EXCLUSIVE_PROCESS, because EXCLUSIVE_THREAD was deprecated and then removed some time ago.

Comment: and, for example, instead of specifying `-c 0` for DEFAULT, you can also specify `-c DEFAULT`

Answer (score 8):

In order to know the current `Compute Mode`, use the following command

```
nvidia-smi  --query | grep 'Compute Mode'
```

In order to **set** the `Compute Mode`, use the following command

```
sudo nvidia-smi -c $i
```

Where $i could be 0, 1, 2 or 3. Meaning of these numbers are given below -

```
0 Default
1 Exclusive_Thread
2 Prohibited 
3 Exclusive_Process
```

Answer to your question

```
sudo nvidia-smi -c 0
```

This will set all GPUs in default mode. Use `-i 0` flag if you want to apply it only to GPU 0.

Comment: Brief comment that Exclusive_Thread is deprecated with newer drivers
```
sudo nvidia-smi -c 1
Warning: Exclusive_Thread was deprecated! Setting Exclusive_Process instead.
Set compute mode to EXCLUSIVE_PROCESS for GPU 00000000:3B:00.0.
Warning: Exclusive_Thread was deprecated! Setting Exclusive_Process instead.
Set compute mode to EXCLUSIVE_PROCESS for GPU 00000000:AF:00.0.
All done.
```